# Get tweet count of shares for multiple URLs with one request

Tags: twitter

I know how to get the tweet count of shares for one URL with the following request:

https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=[URL]

What I don't know is how to get the tweet count of shares for multiple URLs with just one request, maybe something like this:

cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=[URL1,URL2,URL3,...]

Facebook already has this functionality:

graph.facebook.com/?ids=[URL1,URL2,URL3,...]

I was wondering if Twitter has this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is is supported.

Also this URL is not supposed to be available for the public and you shouldn't use it, especially since Twitter plans to shut it down in the near future (this month, I think).

You should look into the the Twitter REST and Streaming APIs instead.

https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Twitter says one of these should be used, these are officially supported.

But so far, I haven't found a way to easily query the number of tweets for a URL using these APIs though.